# Custom UIControl gets touchesCancelled when scrolling; how do I disable scroll?

Tags: iphone, uikit, uiscrollview, uicontrol

I'm writing a UISwitch replacement (with custom graphics). I've overridden touchesMoved and friends, so that you can drag the widget between Yes and No, just as with UISwitch.

If you place it in a scroll view, touches will be cancelled if the user moves her finger the tiniest bit diagonally instead of perfectly horizontally, and scrolling kicks in instead. I've noted that UISwitch and UIButton do not exhibit this behavior, and scrolling never kicks in while manipulating these controls.

How can I tell UIKit that I want exclusive control over these touches, in effect disabling scroll in touchesBegan and enabling scroll in ended/cancelled? I'm sure there's something obvious, but I've looked through the headers and documentation for UIControl, UIResponder, UIView and UIScrollView and haven't found anything.

Note: I don't want to make a UIScrollView subclass; I can't imagine that being the right solution, the control should be completely standalone.

Comment: I assume simply setting scrollEnabled = NO on your UIScrollView between touch down and touch up isn't an option here?

Comment: @jnic: That correct, I have no reference to the scroll view from the control subclass. A horrible ugly solution would be to iterate superview until I find the closest scroll view and disable that, but I'm trying to find a pretty solution here.

Answer (score 4):

Setting `canCancelContentTouches = NO` in the scroll view, and `exclusiveTouch = YES` in a custom control allows this behaviour, assuming you are happy changing properties on the scroll view.